# What would a WebException for a connection killed by a Heroku server look like?

Tags: http, web, heroku, service, timeout

**Background:**

I am working with an external vendor where requests for a file download go through a web service.  I believe their service is hosted on herokuapp and recently we have been seeing connections get killed after exactly 30 seconds.  99.99% of our requests receive subsecond responses, occasionally one or two requests will take 20+ seconds and for any that hit the 30 second mark we see the issue.  So I only see this issue on about 1/10,000 requests (happens once every few days).

I've done some looking around and the only thing that I've found to be common is that Heroku has a 30 second HTTP request timeout that a few people have issues with and on the server side it's pretty easy to spot one of these.  The issue is we don't have access to server side logs and only have a generic error returning client side.

**What I have tried:**

In terms of debugging I have pointed the service endpoint to a local dummy web service that literally just sleeps for 3 minutes and it doesn't timeout until the 120 second mark (which is our server's default).

Error in WebException message after 30 seconds to external vendor's service: *"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive"*

As a note to the above error message, tls1.2 is already being forced for these requests.

**Actual Question:**

Is it possible based on these logs that Heroku is actually killing this connection server side and this would result in the generic error seen?

**Sources:**

Heroku HTTP request timeouts: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

Outsystems blaming these errors on remote server, not client: https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/15641/tip-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-rece/

Comment: Heroku does definitely have this limitation in their routing-layer, that's why people should offload file-downloads or similar to other services. I'm not sure which error the client actually sees then. 

I would recommend you just setting up a small Heroku app on your own and trying for yourself. There are plenty of tutorials for the web framework of your choice.

Comment: @DenisCornehl, these downloads are 1 page pdfs which normally take subsecond.  With that even being said, does it just not make sense for the external vendor to claim their timeout is set to 60 seconds if they're on heroku?  From what I've seen there's no real workaround for this timeout (outside of a heartbeat ping which they are not doing).

Comment: If they are on heroku, I don't see any way to circumvent the 30 seconds timeout, apart from streaming and heartbeats, also see [their documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout)